# AVPlayer counterpart of AVAudioPlayer's 'playAtTime'

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I want to play an audio 1 second after the view appears. This is easy to do with `AVAudioPlayer` using

```
[myAudioPlayer playAtTime:myAudioPlaer.deviceCurrentTime + 1.0];
```

But I have to use `AVPlayer` for some reasons.

Does `AVPlayer` have a method like `AVAudioPlayer's` `playAtTime`?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same like this

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // prefrom your task
});
```